# header, footer or main element inside dialog element in html5

Tags: html, header, dialog, program-entry-point

Is semantically correct to use a header, footer o main elements inside a dialog component in Html5?.

I want to build a complex modal view with options about articles in my main page content. I am wondering if is correct use html5 as follows

```
  <dialog> 
    <header>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <button> Save </button>
    </header>
    <main>
        <!--modal view options-->
    </main>

  </dialog>
```

Answer (score 7):

Only the `<main>` tag shouldn't be there.

As copied from W3schools:

> The header element represents a container for introductory content or a set  of navigational links.

And:

> You *can have several* header elements in one document.

This applies to the header *and* the footer.

but then there is this:

> There must not be more than one *main* element in a document. The main element must NOT be a descendant of an article, aside, footer, header, or nav element.

So, to say it in a short way:

you *can* use multiple `<header>` and `<footer>` tags in your document, but you're better of using a `<div>` instead of your `<main>`

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please upvote and / or accept this answer. It will help others find it and will stop this question from going back on top

Answer (score 7):

### Tl;dr

Using `header`, `footer` or `main` in the `dialog` element for the purpose of describing this dialog's content **is not semantically correct**.

---

### About `header` and `footer`

Only **Sectioning content** elements (or body) define a semantic scope that is applied to `header` and `footer`. `dialog` is not a sectioning content ([source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#sectioning-content)). So, `header` and `footer` placed within `dialog` will describe the closest sectioning content or body, **not a `dialog` itself**.

### About `main` element

There are 3 important rules to remember when using `main` element ([source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-main-element)):

1. it should be used only to represent the dominant contents of the document (`dialog`'s content is not likely to be the dominant content),
2. there can be only one `main` element without `hidden` attribute on the webpage at the same time (which means you would need to add `hidden` attribute on your general `main` page element),
3. `main` element ancestors can only be `html`, `body`, `div` or `form` elements without an accessible name. `main` cannot be contained within anything else, including autonomous custom elements.

So, 3rd point **makes it impossible to use `main` element inside of a `dialog`**. And 1st and 2nd make it **really hard**.

---

### Solution

Good solution in this case would be to either drop using of those elements or to wrap `dialog`'s content with a `section` element to be able to provide semantic `header` and `footer`.

```html
  <dialog>
    <section>
      <header><!-- header content --></header>
      <div>
        <!-- modal content -->
      </div>
      <footer><!-- footer content --></footer>
    </section>
  </dialog>
```